# How to define a multi-dimensional array?

Tags: php, arrays

I want to construct the following details in an array:

[image: http://i59.tinypic.com/2ynmf83.png]

How can I do that?

```
$pokemon = array
(
    array(values...,values...),
    array(values...,values...),
    array(values...,values...);
);
```

I don't think the above would help me.. cause I want to name even the rows..i.e pokemon1,pokemon2.. so on..

So I can use it efficiently in my code!?? I want to know how to structure it into an array!

Comment: `array(array('name' => ..., 'level' => ..., 'health' => ...), ...)`

Comment: why haven't you search before asking?

Comment: sounds like `$pokemons = array("pokemon1" => array("hp" => 90, "moveSet" => array("move1","move2")), "pokemon2" => array([..]), "pokemon3" => array([...]) [...]);` You really should use multi multidimensional arrays if I've understood what you want to do. Pokemons are not easy to describe in a single multi-dimensional array :D

Comment: Thnk Briosheje!! I have got a good idea abt it ;)

Comment: $pokemon1 isn't a valid element for your array. Do you even have an idea of what an array is and how it is supposed to be declared / filled?

Comment: Actually I know the use of single...but never came across multi-dimensional..so it may be logical-less :P ..but thnks anyways!

Comment: @user3672971: a multi dimensional array is an array that contains other arrays. In your case, the best way to go is make a generic array called, for instance $pokemons (example). At this point, each element of this array would be a **key**, containing the pokemon name (example: bulbasaur) and, foreach key, you will have **an array** containing other keys and other values. Example with bulbasaur: `$pokemons = array("Bulbasaur" => array("HP" => 20));` in this way, you can access to bulbasaur's hps in this way: `echo $pokemons["Bulbasaur"]["HP"];` .

Answer (score 1):

You mean :

```
$pokemon1 = "poke1";
$pokemon2 = "poke2";
$pokemon3 = "poke3";

$pokemon = array (  array($pokemon1, 'level' => "test", 'health' => "test"), 
                    array($pokemon2, 'level' => "test", 'health' => "test"), 
                    array($pokemon3, 'level' => "test", 'health' => "test")
                );


var_dump($pokemon);


array(3) {
  [0]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(5) "poke1"
    ["level"]=>
    string(4) "test"
    ["health"]=>
    string(4) "test"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(5) "poke2"
    ["level"]=>
    string(4) "test"
    ["health"]=>
    string(4) "test"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(5) "poke3"
    ["level"]=>
    string(4) "test"
    ["health"]=>
    string(4) "test"
  }
}
```

Comment: how do you expect $pokemon1, $pokemon2 and $pokemon3 to work if you didn't declare them? That's an array, first you should be expecting a => and not a =, then you should have a KEY, not a variable.

Answer (score 0):

```
$multiArray[] = array("Pokemon1", "level", "health");
$multiArray[] = array("Pokemon2", "level", "health");
```

Take a look at https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php